# How to install numpy and scipy on Windows XP

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a problem installing Numpy and Scipy from

http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Windows

I went to download page and downloaded .exe files for Python26. I have Python26 on my machine. After installation, I tried

```
>>> import nympy, scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nympy
>>>
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with `numpy` instead of `nympy`